# BibTeX alpha long keys cause indentation of entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, indentation

I'm using BibTeX with the alpha style to keep track of my references. Whenever there is an entry with 4 or more authors, the entry id composed of their names and publication years causes the first line of the entry to be indented, thereby messing up the alignment of the whole entry.

What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: I did a quick test -- with the `alpha` style, "long" keys will increase the indentation of *every* line of *every* entry. Therefore please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Many Bibtex styles support control over indentation using the `bibhang` dimension, although I haven't found an alphanumeric style that supports it.

The code below shows how support for `\bibhang` can be added to vanilla Bibtex, so that it can be used with `alpha.bst`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Absurd indent to show off what is happening
\newlength\bibhang
\setlength\bibhang{9em} 

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

%%Redefine \bibitem to ensure bibhang is used

%%This could conflict with packages that want %%to change these parameters
\def\setbibindent{
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibhang}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}}
\let\urbibitem=\bibitem
\def\bibitem{\setbibindent\urbibitem}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\nocite[*]

\bibliography{examplebib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: works only for author&year citation!

Comment: @Tobiask - Actually, it is not restricted to author–year, since it works for numeric citations, but it doesn't work with alpha.  I've changed the answer to show how support for \bibhang can be added to documents using alpha.bst